# Log rotation in ros

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a clean and standard way to have a log rotation in my program. Through this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/229966/does-ros-have-rolling-log-files-ability-to-limit-total-size/?answer=232577#post-id-232577) I found [this PR](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/551) that mentioned this feature but currently has not merged and does not seem have a plan to merge in the near future. Also  by looking at the answer I tried to work with [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and with some script [like this](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-system-daemon/blob/master/debian/ros-system-daemon.ros.logrotate) I wrote a script to rotate my logs (I had to use copytruncate) but there is a annoying problem with this approach.

As [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/71348) mentions there is a conflict between logrotate and log4j, log4j track the position of file and when we truncate it for being compatible unix system adds some null characters before the current position of log and finally we get the same file size and rotation does not mean anything.

I think log rotation is an important feature for a program in a medium scale and above, and I wonder how some big real robot softwares implement this feature and is it possible to run a big project without this feature, I have a limited resource but I hope to able to keep all information that I log during runtime.

Can someone suggest me a solution to this and explain why does not this feature  exist in ros log (am I wrong about importance of this feature or not)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267503/log-rotation-in-ros/) by [MohsenTamiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/17846/mohsentamiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MohsenTamiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/17846/mohsentamiz/) on 2017-07-29**:
Could anyone suggest me a starting point for solving this problem?

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2017-11-27**:
Hi Mohsen, have you solved this problem? I'm also facing it.

**Comment by [MohsenTamiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/17846/mohsentamiz/) on 2017-12-09**:
No I`m still looking for a proper solution of it, currently we just try to log as much as we hope not floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI Mohsen,

I've implemented a logrotate script that cleans the ROS log folder and creates tar.gz files for old logs. Make sure you have logrotate installed and place the script inside your /etc/logrotate.d folder. Also, make sure to replace the paths on the logrotate script with your own paths.

https://github.com/lucascoelhof/ros_logrotate

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0